# How to subscribe new user to notifications?

Tags: java, postgresql, sonarqube, postgresql-9.4, sonarqube5.2

I have set up SonarQube 5.2 installation, and I want to enable notifications for new users by default. What I mean is [these checkboxes in user profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1egWW.png).
I couldn't find an answer in the documentation, the available plugins, the Internet, if anybody had a similar question. What I have found so far is user properties in the SQ database:

```
sonar=# select * from properties where user_id=6;
 id |                          prop_key                           | resource_id | text_value | user_id 
----+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+------------+---------
 85 | favourite                                                   |        3260 |            |       6
 91 | notification.ChangesOnMyIssue.EmailNotificationChannel      |             | true       |       6
 92 | notification.NewFalsePositiveIssue.EmailNotificationChannel |             | true       |       6
 93 | notification.SQ-MyNewIssues.EmailNotificationChannel        |             | true       |       6
 94 | notification.NewIssues.EmailNotificationChannel             |             | true       |       6
 95 | notification.NewAlerts.EmailNotificationChannel             |             | true       |       6
(6 rows)
```

I have even searched through the source code, but haven't found how to set user properties on user registration. What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Notifications+-+Administration) has been updated to be specific on this case: no functionality is provided to subscribe another user to notifications. Each user must choose to receive notifications himself.

Comment: Thank you for the timely response! I assume this case is not something on SQ development roadmap?

Comment: Nope. People need to choose to spam themselves. :-)

Comment: One of the worst decision SQ has ever made. Let the user choose how they want to use SQ.

Answer (score 2):

While I understand wanting people to choose spam for themselves, our company needs to require developers to immediately remediate their security issues. Because of this, we require developers to get notifications so that they are aware of issues. There are simply too many of them to constantly "use the act of persuasion".

Here is the insert statement I've used to turn on "My New Issues" notification for all developers that don't already have the notification on:

```
INSERT INTO properties 
        (prop_key, 
         resource_id, 
         user_id, 
         is_empty, 
         text_value, 
         clob_value, 
         created_at)
SELECT 'notification.SQ-MyNewIssues.EmailNotificationChannel', 
       NULL, 
       u.id, 
       0, 
       'true', 
       NULL, 
       Unix_timestamp(Now()) 
FROM   users u 
       LEFT JOIN properties p 
              ON ( u.id = p.user_id 
                   AND 
       p.prop_key = 'notification.SQ-MyNewIssues.EmailNotificationChannel' ) 
WHERE  p.user_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks you! awsome - working fine for me SonarQube Version 6.7.5