# Auto subscribe for new issues notifications for all the users in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube is able to notify the new issues introduced by a specific user when the user subscribes to the"my new issues" under "MyAccount->Notifications" only.

This functionality is as per the documentation https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Notifications+-+Administration

Iam curious to know is there any way for Admin to subscribe the notifications of all the users instead of every user login and subscribe to the Notifications themselves?

or put it in other way

Can we specify about the notifications  when the user is created/imported from the ldap so that by default notifications are subscribed/enabled for the users?

Iam using SonarQube5.6.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The documentation mentioned in your question says: "There is no admin functionality to proactively subscribe another user". You could go messing around in the SonarQube database but that is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your response, will try it out.

Comment: It's already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43683034/2143846